# Some app or service block macbook from locking

Tags: macos, mojave

I have default settings for sleep mode. But still if go away and return to my macbook I see that it is not locked. I guess some app blocks it from locking. How can I find which one?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask you to please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/367446/edit) your question to clarify what your settings actually are in both the Energy Saver preference pane and within the General tab of the Security & Privacy preference pane? Perhaps including screenshots is the way to go.

Comment: Hello @Monomeeth ! done

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, how long are you waiting before coming back to your MacBook? And, when you do come back, is it in sleep mode but not requiring a password, or is it not going to sleep at all? Also, what model MacBook do you have?

Comment: It can be couple of hours. And when I come back macbook has the same view as when I left and the screen is not even dimmed

Comment: And your model of MacBook?

Comment: A typical first step to troubleshoot power management is to do an [SMC reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and for good measure also a [NVRAM reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).

Comment: added a screenshot of model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the first thing I'd do is boot your MacBook in Safe mode and test to see what happens.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps to boot your Mac into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window
5. Now log into your Mac and (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice)
6. Now test to see if your MacBook goes to sleep or not
7. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your Mac as normal
8. Once again, test to see if your Mac goes to sleep

If you find that your MacBook still doesn't go to sleep while in Safe Mode or when logged in normally afterwards, then proceed below to resetting your SMC.

If on the other hand you find that your MacBook does go to sleep in Safe Mode, but still doesn't when you're logged in normally, then let me know and we'll troubleshoot further.

**Resetting your SMC**

Your System Management Controller (SMC) manages a whole range of functions relating to power, charging, your Mac's thermal environment, and so on. Since you're having problems with your Mac going to sleep, this is a good thing to try.

However, since you haven't specified your model of MacBook, refer to [How to reset the System Management Controller (SMC) on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201585) on Apple's website. Please read through this page carefully as the instructions differ for different models of Mac.

Comment: seems reset of SMC did help